# Images broken on a Stack Overflow blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, blog

On the [So long Winter Bash 2014](http:////stackoverflow.blog/2015/01/06/so-long-winter-bash-2014/) blog post, nearly all the images are broken. I assume this is because they are all hosted on `stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/` rather than `zgab33vy595fw5zq-zippykid.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/`, and they got destroyed in the removal of Blog Overflow. I looked around at a few other blog posts, and this post seems to be the only one having an issue.

Comment: The images appear correctly in the Jekyll version of that post on GitHub (see https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/blob/master/_posts/2015-01-06-so-long-winter-bash-2014.markdown) which suggests this may have been an issue with the most recent migration...

Comment: The images [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) are also broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated the images in the first post. The second post in the comments seems to be working now as well. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Thanks! Images work now, but the majority of the images' links are broken. For example: both images in the second row link to dustin's profile, when the first should link to mine.