# The images on the stack snippets blog post are broken

Tags: bug, images, blog, imgur

On [this Stack Overflow blog post about stack snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), none of the images show up for me. Several others [say the same](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36295844#36295844).

I can still click the broken image links and they open on imgur normally.

The images in [other SO blog posts](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/11/10/updating-stack-overflow/) I've checked seem to work fine. This includes https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/01/06/so-long-winter-bash-2014/ which are broken according to [Images broken on a Stack Overflow blog post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291840/images-broken-on-a-stack-overflow-blog-post).

Comment: The `<img>` sources aren't Imgur, eg: https://stackoverflow.blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/YMvu1.png. The images are also links (`<a>`) which lead to valid Imgur images.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm not sure it's the same issue. I can see those images.

Comment: @HelkaHomba they probably fixed them, but since it's not yet marked as completed maybe better put all those together, instead of a new bug report for every blog post with broken images.